# Using sorted to sort a list of objects

Tags: python, sorting

Using a for loop like this:

```
for k in time :
        def byPrice(stock):
            st = stock.get_momentum
            return st[k]
        s = sorted(obj, key=byPrice)
```

I want to sort the list of the `stock` objects by the kth item in the momentum array within each stock object.

```
class stock:
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.lens = len(price)

    def get_momentum(self):
        momentum = []
        for i in np.arange(lens):
             count = close[i]/close[i-60]
             momentum.append(count)
        return momentum
```

But I got a warning saying `'method' object is not subscriptable`. And the error is at the line `st[k]`

Comment: You aren't calling `get_momentum`. Do `st = stock.get_momentum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add parentheses:

```
for k in time :
        def byPrice(stock):
            st = stock.get_momentum()
            return st[k]
        s = sorted(obj, key=byPrice)
```

You need to actually call your method. Otherwise, `st` is the method object, and `st[k]` makes no sense.

You could also do this without defining `byPrice` with

```
s = sorted(obj, key=lambda stock:stock.get_momentum()[k])
```

(arguably harder to read, though). Or you could define `byPrice` outside the loop and have it take `k` as another argument.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting variable `st` to the actual class method `stock.get_momentum`, and a method/function object doesn't have index-based access. That's what `not subscriptable` means.

Just a minor typo, happens all the time! Change `st = stock.get_momentum` to `st = stock.get_momentum()`.